# Join Table from two different DB in Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysqljs

I want to do joins on the table from two DBS.

What I did is.

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');


var poolCluster = mysql.createPoolCluster();
var configDB=require('../config');
let config={};
config['settlement']={...configDB['settlementDB']};

config['vch']={...configDB['vchSystemDB']};

poolCluster.add('settlement', config['settlement']); // add a named configuration
poolCluster.add('vch', config['vch']);

let query="SELECT * from settlement.VoucherAndSettlementDetails  VoucherAndSettlementDetails JOIN vch.voucher voucher on VoucherAndSettlementDetails.voucherId = voucher.vchid  "


poolCluster.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    if(err) console.log("error poll connection",err);
    connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
        console.log("fields ",fields)
        console.log("results ",results)
        if (error){
            console.log('error is ',error);
            return;
        }
    });

});
```

I am getting following Error :

```
code: 'ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE',
errno: 1146,
sqlMessage: "Table 'vch.voucher' doesn't exist"
```

Can someone help me to do it? I am not understanding on which connection object query should be performed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using fully qualified database name

`SELECT * from settlementDB.VoucherAndSettlementDetails  VoucherAndSettlementDetails JOIN vchSystemDB.voucher voucher on VoucherAndSettlementDetails.voucherId = voucher.vchid`